# Why do I get nan when assigning with loc

Tags: python, pandas

consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5), list('ABCDE'), list('abcde'))
print(df)

    a   b   c   d   e
A   0   1   2   3   4
B   5   6   7   8   9
C  10  11  12  13  14
D  15  16  17  18  19
E  20  21  22  23  24
```

---

I want to replace the values in row `'A'` with the corresponding values in row `'E'` only where the values in row `'D'` are equal to zero mod three

I create the boolean mask

```
mask = df.loc['D'] % 3 == 0
```

Then I make my assignment

```
df.loc['A'] = df.loc['E', mask]
```

However, I now have `np.nan` in some of my columns and my whole dataframe is now `float`

```
print(df)

      a     b     c     d     e
A  20.0   NaN   NaN  23.0   NaN
B   5.0   6.0   7.0   8.0   9.0
C  10.0  11.0  12.0  13.0  14.0
D  15.0  16.0  17.0  18.0  19.0
E  20.0  21.0  22.0  23.0  24.0
```

How should I go about getting this result?

```
    a   b   c   d   e
A  20   1   2  23   4
B   5   6   7   8   9
C  10  11  12  13  14
D  15  16  17  18  19
E  20  21  22  23  24
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include `mask` in your `loc` for row `'A'` instead of row `'E'`:

```
df.loc['A', mask] =  df.loc['E']
```

The reason you're seeing `NaN` values is that you're reassigning all of row `'A'` as just the masked version of row `'E'`.  The masked version of row `'E'` is missing entries for some columns, so they get filled with `NaN`.  The dtype for `NaN` is `float`, which forces all of the other integer values to be floats.  By using `mask` on row `'A'` instead, you're only assigning to the locations you want to update.

The resulting output:

```
    a   b   c   d   e
A  20   1   2  23   4
B   5   6   7   8   9
C  10  11  12  13  14
D  15  16  17  18  19
E  20  21  22  23  24
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
In [172]: df.loc['A', df.columns[df.loc['D'] % 3 == 0]] = df.loc['E']

In [173]: df
Out[173]:
    a   b   c   d   e
A  20   1   2  23   4
B   5   6   7   8   9
C  10  11  12  13  14
D  15  16  17  18  19
E  20  21  22  23  24
```